# Shortcode example for Mautic Form Embed

Tags: wordpress, mautic

where can I find the shortcode in wordpress? to modify the mauticform id
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Goto Plugin directory (/wp-content/plugins/)

**Step 2:** find folder WP Mautic.

**Step 3:** Open "WP Mautic.php" in root directory in notepad++.

**Step 4:** find in files "put full path of plugin" and as search term `add_shortcode('mauticform'`

**Step 5:**  That's it.

**Referance Link :**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mautic/